# TCP server in c

Tags: c, sockets, gcc, networking

I am trying to make tcp server and client so that message i send from server to client will be printed to stdout

i have macbook and linux. I want to have server on macbook and client on linux.

output of ip addr on linux : `inet 10.0.1.175/24 brd 10.0.1.255`

output of ifconfig on mac is: `inet 10.0.1.165`

on both machines i am compiling with command:

```
gcc tcp_server_01.c -o server
```

```
gcc tcp_client_01.c -o client
```

macbook is m1

linux is orange pi 5 with armbian

code for tcp_server_01.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>

#include <unistd.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main ()
{
  char server_message[250] = "message was recived form MB \n\r";

  //create socket
  int server_socket;
  server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  //define addres structure
  struct sockaddr_in server_addres;
  server_addres.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server_addres.sin_port = htons(5067);
  server_addres.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.1.165"); //INADDR_ANY

  //bind socket to specified ip and port
  int n = bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addres, sizeof(server_addres));
  //int n = bind(server_socket, &server_addres.sin_addr) 

  perror("error");

  //Listen for connections
  listen(server_socket, 1);

  int client_socket;
  client_socket = accept(server_socket, NULL, NULL);

  //send message
  send(client_socket, server_message, sizeof(server_message), 0);

  //colose socket
  close(server_socket);
  return 0;
}
```

code for tcp_client_01.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
  //coreate a socket
  int network_socket;
  network_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  // specify an adress for socket
  struct sockaddr_in server_address;
  server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server_address.sin_port = htons(5067); 
  server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.1.165"); //INADDR_ANY

  int connection_status = connect(network_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));

  //check for errors
  if (connection_status == 0)
  {
    printf("connection sucessfull\n%i", connection_status);
    perror("Error");
  }else 
  {
    perror("Error");
    //printf("connection unsucesfull\n");
  }

  //string for server_response
  char server_response[250];

  //recive data from server 
  recv(network_socket, &server_response, sizeof(server_response), 0);

  //print recived data
  printf("message form server: %s\n", server_response);

  //colose socket
  close(network_socket);

  return 0;
}
```

i was folowing this youtube video: https://youtu.be/LtXEMwSG5-8

if i replace `inet_addr("10.0.1.165")` whit `INADDR_ANY` in both scripts and run them both on local machine it works instantly.

When i tun them on separate machines both of scipts run forever.

`./server` on mac outputs: `error: Undefined error: 0`

`./client` on linux outputs nothing

**EDIT:**

I have rewritten both functions and fixed errors when I run them still no output.
this is tcp_server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main ()
{
  char server_message[250] = "message was recived form AMB \n\r";

  //coresreate socket
  int server_socket;
  if((server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
  {
    perror("socket");
    return 0;
  }

  //define addres structure
  struct sockaddr_in server_addres;
  server_addres.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server_addres.sin_port = htons(5067);
  server_addres.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.1.165"); //INDOOR_ANY

  //bind socket to specified ip and port
  if(bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addres, sizeof(server_addres)) != 0)
  {
    perror("bind");
    return 0;
  }
  //int n = bind(server_socket, &server_addres.sin_addr) 


  //Listen for connections
  if(listen(server_socket, 1) !=0)
  {
    perror("listen");
    return 0;
  }


  int client_socket;
  if((client_socket = accept(server_socket, NULL, NULL)) == -1)
  {
    perror("accept");
    return 0;
  }

  //send message
  if(send(client_socket, server_message, sizeof(server_message), 0) == -1)
  {
    perror("send");
    return 0;
  }

  //colose socket
  close(server_socket);
  return 0;
}
```

this is tcp_client.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
  //coreate a socket
  int network_socket;
  if((network_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
  {
    perror("socket creation");
    return 0;
  }

  // specify an adress for socket
  struct sockaddr_in server_address;
  server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server_address.sin_port = htons(5067); 
  server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.1.165"); //INADDR_ANY

  if(connect(network_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address)) != 0)
  {
    perror("socket connection");
    return 0;
  }

  //string for server_response
  char server_response[250];

  //recive data from server 
  if(recv(network_socket, &server_response, sizeof(server_response), 0) == -1)
  {
    perror("reciving socket");
    return 0;
  }

  //print recived data
  printf("message form server: %s\n", server_response);

  //colose socket
  close(network_socket);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `perror("error");`? Don't do that unless there's an actual error. And add some actual error checking, where you check what all your functions are returning.

Comment: Also, if there's an error, don't just let the programs continue as if nothing happened.

Comment: You are wasting time if you are not checking all return values.  It's an important lesson.  When troubleshooting client/server, replace either end with a know good working implementation so you can quick determine which is side is the problem.   netcat or socat are useful tools to this end.  Another key tool to learn is wireshark so you can inspect what goes over the wire.